# How to use terraform to enable Managed private endpoint on datafactory azure sql database linked service

Tags: sql-server, azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use terraform to create adf linked services however the terraform resource  doesn't give the option to select an already existing managed private endpoint for the linked service to communicate over but when creating from the portal, this is possible. bellow is my code

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "process-adf" {
  resource_group_name             = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  location                        = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  name                            = "adf"
  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
  public_network_enabled          = false
  tags                            = var.tags
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database" "process-mssql-adf" {
  name                     = "mssql-adf"
  data_factory_id          = azurerm_data_factory.process-adf.id
  integration_runtime_name = azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure.adf.id
  connection_string        = "data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=admin;Password=password;integrated security=True;encrypt=True;connection timeout=30"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint" "adf-msssql-pe" {
  name               = "adf"
  data_factory_id    = azurerm_data_factory.process-adf.id
  target_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.process-control.id
  subresource_name   = "sqlServer"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure" "adf" {
  name                    = "adf"
  data_factory_id         = azurerm_data_factory.process-adf.id
  location                = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  virtual_network_enabled = true
}
```

how do i point the resource `azurerm_data_factory_linked_service_azure_sql_database` to the resource `azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint` ?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: In my configuration, selection is done automatically as long as I have un private managed end point